# CSS Force odd number of elements per line

Tags: css, line-breaks

I have a bunch of inline-block elements. Odd and even numbered elements are styled differently, so I want them to line break only after an odd number of elements per row, to preserve the grid pattern when the screen is resized. The elements are all the same size, if that matters.

```
.thing{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:5px;
}
.thing:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 0 20px;
}
.thing:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px 0;
}
/* something that will only allow line breaks after 1st or 3rd or 5th etc element  */
```

Is there a way to do this elegantly? I suppose theoretically it may be possible to just do a bunch of media query blocks for each "case" and use :nth-child():after to force a line break, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css grid to display 3 per row (or 5 or whatever desired).

```css
.wrap-things {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.thing {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin: auto;
}
.thing:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 0 20px;
}
.thing:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-things">
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would work if I'm trying for an even number of elements per line, but I'm going for odd. Also, I'm trying to avoid semantically meaningless containers and such as much as possible, so as to avoid confusing things like screenreaders.

Comment: Going for odd, you could wrap three `.thing` in the `.wrap-things`. This still doesn't change the fact that there would be a number of meaningless containers. This is the only way that I can see getting it to work besides creating a ton of break points. Sorry that it wasn't more helpful. You could try grid spec but browser support is not 100% yet. http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: @Rose Liu: Screen readers should be smart enough to understand that semantically meaningless elements are just that: meaningless.

Comment: @JRoss Wrapping three things in the `.wrap-thing` doesn't force it to display an odd number of elements in a row. It could, for example, fit six in a row.